# Using Gitihub actions for CI CD on aws ec2 machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2, github-actions

i am new github actions workflow and was wondering that is it possible that i set my ec2 machine directly for CI and CD after every push.

I have seen that it is possible with ECS , but i wanted a straight forward solution as we are trying this out on our Dev environment we don't want over shoot our budget.

is it possible , if yes how can i achieve it ?

Comment: When you ask for CICD on EC2, is it for provisioning, building and deploying on EC2 servers or just deploying generated build/package from Actions on to EC2?

Comment: @saurabh14292 I have an apache server running on my machine. I don't need to spin up a new instance. I want to build my code when there is a push to my master and then deploy it onto my machine.

Answer (score 5):

If you build your code in GitHub Actions, and just want to copy the package over existing EC2, you can use SCP files action plugin

https://github.com/marketplace/actions/scp-files

```
- name: copy file via ssh key
  uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
  with:
    host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
    username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
    port: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
    key: ${{ secrets.KEY }}
    source: "tests/a.txt,tests/b.txt"
    target: "test"
```

If you have any other AWS resource which interacts with EC2 (or any other AWS service) and you want to use AWS CLI, you can use AWS Credentials Action

https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials

```
- name: Configure AWS credentials from Test account
  uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
  with:
     aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.TEST_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
     aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.TEST_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
     aws-region: us-east-1

 - name: Copy files to the test website with the AWS CLI
   run: |
     aws s3 sync . s3://my-s3-test-website-bucket
```

Comment: thank you for the answer you cleared a lot of things which were blurred to me. I have a question CI. How GitHub builds? does it create a new image for every trigger or how does it work?

Comment: GitHub Actions provides you platform to create your build. It basically provides you compute power as container and you can execute your build scripts within it. You control when to trigger, how to trigger, how to build and where to store. You do not to provision dedicated VM for "building" your packages. It is provisioned on demand.

Comment: is it possible to build on my own EC2 machine?

Comment: Yes, Self Hosted runners. https://help.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/about-self-hosted-runners

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://medium.com/codemonday/github-actions-for-ci-cd-with-ec2-codedeploy-and-s3-e93e75bf1ce0) there is a nice article. The goal of article is to build a CI/CD stack with Github Actions + AWS EC2, CodeDeploy and S3.